# How can I display data from a related model in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two models

```
class Car
    has_many :engines                         
end

class Engine
    belongs_to :car
end
```

In the car form I have a select field where the user can select the engine type. The list might be "1.4L; 1.6L; 2.0L..."

Lets say I want to display additional information from the Engine model when the user selects a engine. This should be displayed on the Car form. This might be e.g. BHP, max revs, ...etc

How do I set something like this up. I guess there are two aspects:

1. How to display data from the engine
   model on the car form without using
   a field (this data is not editable).
2. How to update this data dynamically
       when the user selects an option in
       the select field.

Can anyone point me towards a starting point for this. I'm a bit lost where to begin.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with collection_select in your form, you are setting two arguments, like :id and :name in your collection_select call. :id is the method called to determine the value for the option tag and :name is the method used to display the option tag's content.

Solution: Create a method (e.g. :name_for_select) in your engine model which returns a string with more information about your engine and call collection_select with :id, :name_for_select instead.

Comment: hi pduersteler thanks for the suggestion. This looks promising, I'm going through the API trying to understand a bit more.

Comment: was in a hurry, here's an untested example: http://pastie.org/2046841, nice to read: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: Hi pduersteler, this isn't exactly the answer I was looking for. I had hoped to display the related data directly on the form. However this is an elegant alternative, and I've learned something new. I'm going to use this for now, but will keep searching for the other approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is called a nested form, and if you google that you will find a lot of hints and tips. E.g. check out [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-1) and [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) tutorial.

You should also consider using a form builder like [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) or [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form): they have a lot of helpers to make life easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. A nested form is not really what I'm looking for. The select engine field is tied to engine_Id on the car model. The related engine data though should be displayed as though it were a show rather than an edit template. I.e. This data is for reference and not editable in this view. Do I make sense. I guess I could do this with a engine partial to show the data, and an ajax event on the select field to refresh the data. Does this sound like the right approach? Can you recommend an Ajax for dummies guide to help me learn how to put this together? Thanks.

Comment: A nested form is called that way, because you edit in one form the properties of an object, and one or more nested objects. In your case it would always be just one nested object, but it still is a nested object, so a nested form. So the tutorials are really a good start. A form has a single post action, i think it is best to send your nested objects data along. On the other hand, if you are looking for some kind of editing inside a `show`-page, check out my gem for inline editing (also allowing select boxes): https://github.com/nathanvda/on_the_spot. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ow i am starting to see the light here. Do you have a limited but fixed set of engines? And you just want to link a car to an existing engine. And when the engine changes, you want to display the details of that engine? Yes?

Comment: hi nathanvda, yes that's right. I just need to display details of the engine. Engines are selected from a fixed list, and no editing is required. Simply reference information.